# Как найти и удалить директорию, изменённую 7 дней назад?

Tags: linux

Всем привет!

Как правильно найти директорию, которая изменялась 7 дней назад и удалить ее полностью?

Использую команду:

```
find /folder/folder1/* -mtime +7 -delete
```

Но удаляется только содержимое директорий из folder1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это удаление каталога, который изменился 7 и более дней назад:

```
 find /folder/folder1 -type d -mtime +7 | xargs rm -rf
```

Если надо ровно 7, то `+7` надо заменить на `7`.

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf $(find /folder/folder1 -mtime 7)
```

Comment: У @de_frag правильный вариант - про тип файла я забыл :)

Comment: Ну этот вариант тоже рабочий. Единственное я не знаю каково ограничение на длину конструкции `$(find /folder/folder1 -mtime 7)`. Если там будет миллион результатов поиска, не подавится ли bash...

Comment: @de_frag, да, подавится ) А xargs нормально работает с большим количеством входных аргументов?

Comment: xargs тоже подавится, но у него есть магическая опция `-I{}`. Если сделать вот так: `find /folder/folder1 -type d -mtime +7 | xargs -I{} rm -rf {}`, то rm будет запущен по отдельности на каждый результат поиска, а не на всю строку. Честно признаюсь - не тестировал это на больших количествах. Поэтому за ответ не ручаюсь.

Comment: @de_frag, понял, спасибо за объяснение!